# How to allow minus sign (-) only as the first symbol?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, textbox

I've created a WPF with a TextBox inside it. I allow the user to enter only numbers, backspace, and minus sign. I would like to allow the user to write minus sign only in the first position, before all the rest numbers.
I've tried the following code:

```
private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || (e.KeyChar == 8) || ((e.KeyChar == 45) && (textBox.Text.Length == 0))))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

But it allows the user to write minus only at the beginning, but not when the user would like to edit the first sign of the textbox.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help: [TextBox.SelectStart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionstart?view=net-5.0) and [TextBox.SelectLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionlength?view=net-5.0)

This will tell you where the caret is within the textbox. You can use it to check you are at the start of the text box